# What is the most efficient/fastest way of reading data from a large C# datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl

I am building up an SSIS solution for an ETL process and I'm currently working on the extract section.

Our ETL sources are in different file formats including DB, Excel and CSV and also have different number of columns in each case. So instead of creating a dataflow task for each source I am extracting, I am using a script task which can handle all file types and column numbers.

The script reads the data into a datatable and then bulk inserts it into the database.

This works great on the data I have been testing (approx 30k rows) but I was wondering what happens with more rows and how that would affect performance.

I know the size limitations of a datatable is about 16 million rows and I don't think our data sources will have that many rows, but I am conscious of the effects on performance that a large datatable could have on the entire ETL process.

Would I be better processing the source in batches of say 10,000 to help speed performance?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: SSIS is very dependent on your requirements. Look for the O (Big O) of your processes. For example, do you perform any lookups? They tend to be very expensive as your dataset grows in the destination DB. How do you avoid dupes? Do you have a PK? If not, any indexes? I remember having a requirement to insert the most records I could, reject and report the broken ones. Bulk insert did not help in that case because it fails the entire batch if one record fails.

Comment: Adding up: something else to consider is the traffic bottleneck. Are your files local to your DB? They are probably in a NAS on the network, right? Action: generate a series of dummy files with about 500,000 records and benchmark the different approaches.

Comment: There are no PK, indexes or anything like that at this stage as I am just extracting the raw data from the files and dumping the data from the source into the table. PKs etc will be created in the transform section.

Comment: Loading millions of rows in DataTable might be slow and memory killer. I say, you load data into staging table(s) instead of DataTable. The process all on database.

Comment: I'm using a datatable in order to populate a SQL table, are you saying i could bypass the datatable?

Comment: One more add: a lesson I learned is that SSIS does not handle very well errors captured in the extraction from the files, so what I had to do in previous projects was to extract everything as a large and permissive string and use a data conversion task to cast the data types.